# ValueError when applying conditions on two different arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I want to populate an array depending on two conditions depending on the contents of two different arrays respectively:

```
c = np.where(a == b, 0, 99)
c = np.where(a == 2 and b == 1, -1, c)
```

Arrays a, b and c all have the same shape.
In case the element of array a=2 AND the element of the same index of array b=1, I want to update the element of that index in array c with -1. Otherwise, just keep the previous value of array c.

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Where am I wrong?
Also tried this with no success:

```
c = np.where(a == b, 0, 99)
c = np.where(np.all(a == 2 and b == 1), -1, c)
```

Comment: use () to wrap the conditions and `&` instead of `and`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (a == 2) & (b == 1)
```

is the correct syntax